# Qt set application badge number

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtmacextras

Is it somehow possible to set the application badge number using Qt?

[image: Application badge numer Ubuntu]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not seem to be supported on Ubuntu just yet, but here you can find the Mac version:

[void QtMac::setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(int number)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtmac.html#setApplicationIconBadgeNumber)

You can enable this add-on by putting this into your qmake project file:

```
QT += macextras
```

Comment: Appearantly not, according to the [QX11Info](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QX11Info.html) class

Comment: @Niklas: the problem is that Ubuntu is not only Linux, but a specific distribution. It would be far from being cross-platform, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit confusing because you're using OS X terminology, but you have a screenshot from Ubuntu Unity.  Unity's terminology here would be a "Launcher count" rather than "badge number."

As far as I know at the moment, there's no perfect way to do this on Ubuntu from within a Qt app.  But you do have two options:

1. Ubuntu ships with libunity, which [provides a C API](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/LauncherAPI#Using_the_Launcher_API) for setting the Launcher count.  This method is fine if you only intend your application to run on Ubuntu, but depending on your linking configuration it may not be ideally suited if you want your application to run on other distros.
2. You can set the count via [Launcher DBus API](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/LauncherAPI#Low_level_DBus_API%3A_com.canonical.Unity.LauncherEntry), which is accessible using [Qt's DBus API](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtdbus-index.html).  This doesn't have any additional dependencies, but the DBus protocol isn't guaranteed to remain stable.